# Why would a bash script produce the error "command not founde"?

Tags: bash, shell

What is wrong with the 5th line in this script ( I have included the snippet that gives me the error and the actual error is listed in the bottom after the code and a link to complete script)?

```
#! /bin/bash
INSTALLDIR=/usr/local/mapguideopensource
CLEAN_FLAG=0
while [ $# -gt 0 ]; do    # Until you run out of parameters...
  case "$1" in
    -prefix|--prefix)
        INSTALLDIR="$2"
        shift
        ;;
    -clean|--clean)
        CLEAN_FLAG=1
        shift
        ;;
    -help|--help)
        echo "Usage: $0 (options)"
        echo "Options:"
        echo "  --prefix [installation directory]"
        echo "  --clean [clean all objects and binaries in Oem]"
        echo "  --help [Display usage]"
        exit
        ;;
esac
shift   # Check next set of parameters.
done
```

This is the error i get when i run this bash script on linux (REHL5) :

```
: command not founde 4:  
: command not founde 8:  
: command not founde 8:  
: command not founde 12:  
MapGuide Open Source build script for OEM components  
'/build_oem.sh: line 17: syntax error near unexpected token `in  
'/build_oem.sh: line 17: `    case "$1" in
```

Please note, that the line number above corresponds to the actual script i am running (i have included a link to that script below)
[The original script i am running](http://svn.osgeo.org/mapguide/trunk/MgDev/build_oem.sh)

Comment: Any "what's wrong with this script" question is too localized by definition -- it's only relevant to that single script.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the errors, I'm pretty sure you have carriage returns (aka CR or ^M) at the end of the lines. Windows/DOS text files have carriage return AND linefeed at the end of each line, but unix programs (like bash) just expect a linefeed, and get horribly confused if there's a CR as well. The giveaway is error messages like:

```
: command not founde 4:
```

What this really is is `./build_oem.sh: line 4: ^M: command not found`, but the carriage return makes the terminal go back to the beginning of the line, and write the end of the message over the beginning of the message:

```
./build_oem.sh: line 4: 
: command not found
       |
       V
: command not founde 4:
```

To fix the script, use dos2unix to convert it to proper unix format, then switch to a text editor that saves in unix format.

Comment: Thanks. dos2unix worked for me (I also ran it recursively on other scripts in sub-directories that were called).

Answer (score 4):

What choroba says, but also note that your [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) has to be on the first line (which it is not), otherwise it is useless since it's just a plain comment then and it won't necessarily execute under `bash`.

Answer (score 1):

In the original script, lines 4 and 8 are empty. There is probably some invisible control character on the lines. Try `xxd build_oem.sh`.